# My monitor has a c13 female connector, what can it mean?

Tags: connector, display

I recently bought a pc monitor, and it came with no power adapter, just with a c13 female connector.

What does it mean? Do I have to connect it directly to the power with a male c13 connector? I believe in that because in the back of the monitor it says "POWER: 100-240V~ 50/60Hz 1.5A" , so I think the power adapter can be inside the monitor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do a Google image search for C13 connector?

[image: Kettle Lead]

It is clearly just a standard mains kettle lead type cable that is required.

The fact that it says `100-240V~ 50/60Hz` should have made it immediately obvious that you are supposed to connect 100V to 240V mains AC to it...

Comment: Yes, I did a search. I'm not much into electronics. Moreover, I don't speak english as a first language so I didn't undestood your answer. Could you please say it as it was for a noob? Thanks

Comment: You need a very common cable to connect your Screen to the power outlet in your house. Nothing more.

Comment: The OP said it was a _female_ C13 connector on the monitor.  All of the monitors I see have _male_ C13, so if that's correct (doubtful), then it definitely warrants the question.  spund3: In case there's any confusion, @Tom's picture shows a cord with a  female C13.  If it looks like it will fit in your monitor, then that's all you need.

Comment: @GuitarPicker I presume the OP means male on the monitor - if you look at the shell rather than the pins it is easy to think that the male connector is called a female connector.

Comment: @spund3 buy a cable that fits the hole (like the one pictured), and plug it in to a power socket on your wall.

Comment: It worked, no need of anything more than a c13 wire.